# How can i Get value selected from database to edit

Tags: laravel

Let's say that I select a field the record is added to my database and my form, but when I want to change this field that I selected by another the first field is always by default, it does not return the selected field

Here was my code of create

```
          <select name="father_id" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">--selectionner le parent  svp --</option>
          @foreach($fathers as $father)
              <option value="{{ $eleve->father_id }}" >{{ $father->nom }} 
       {{ $father->prenom }}</option>
          @endforeach  
        </select>
```

this is my edit form   i tried this code

```
       <select name="father_id">
         @foreach($fathers as $father)
        <option value="{{ $father->id }}"@if(old($father->father_id) == 
     "father_id") selected @endif >{{ $father->nom }} {{ $father->prenom }} 
      </option>
    @endforeach  
     </select>
```

my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $note = Note::findOrFail($request->note_id);


    $note->update($request->all());
    session()->flash('success','Cet éléve a été modifié avec succés');


   return redirect()->back();
}
```

the route

```
Route::resource('eleves','EleveController');
```

please help I am really stuck in this error

Comment: Hi, can you provide the route for that?

Comment: @OkereChukwudi i added the route

Answer (score 0):

try it.

```
<select name="father_id">
@foreach($fathers as $father)
    <option value="{{ $father->id }}" {{ old('father_id', '') === $father->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $father->nom }} {{ $father->prenom }} 
    </option>
@endforeach  
</select>
```

Comment: the same error it always returns the first field and not the selected field

Comment: oops!, miss change `old($father->father_id)`. i updated.